# .blur() on every select element after selection

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if there's a way, using jquery, to unfocus EVERY select element after a selection triggered ?

Thanks.

*Note: I know how to do it for one element at a time, this question is for global behavior of select elements*

Comment: Do it just like you would for one element, but select more than one element.

Comment: But doesn't the definition of "focus" mean only one element is selected?

Comment: @KevinB and Jason: I meant unfocus the select element that's focused and have this behavior apply to every select element.

Comment: @frenchie Exactly. Instead of using `#theid`, use `select` so that instead of selecting one select, you are selecting them all. that is what i was suggesting by my first comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go like this, but without much information, I'm not sure it will be correct for you.

```
$('select').on ('change', function () {
    $(this).trigger('blur');
});
```

Note, if by "select" event, you mean a personalized event, juste change "**change**" by your event.

As pointed out by @grinn, you can set the event with a delegation for future created selects :

```
$(document.body).on ('change', 'select', function () {
    $(this).trigger('blur');
});
```

Comment: To have it do it for not just the selects on the page at the time of execution, but also every select that ever get's created, change it to `$(document.body).on("select", "change", function () {`

Comment: ok, thanks. You can also write $(this).blur() instead of $(this).trigger('blur');

Comment: @Grinn It's actually `.on("change","select",`